# Convert string to dictionary format with boolean key-value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I was converting the string to python dictionay thru `ast.literal_eval()`. The string contains boolean values so the `ast.literal_eval()` getting `ValueError`.

From googling, I found that I have to add the statement `ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(json.loads(data)))`to handle boolen data.

But, I'm still getting the same error.

Here is the code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import ast
import json

def main(argv):
    data = argv[1]
    print(argv[1])

    crldix = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(json.loads(data)))

    for drive in crldix['files']:
        print("|{}|{}|".format(drive['name'], drive['boolkey']))

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    retval = main(sys.argv)
    exit(retval)

#eof
```

**Output:**

```
./test.py '{  "files": [   {  "name": "filename",    "boolkey": false  }  ] } '

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 20, in <module>
    retval = main(sys.argv)
  File "./test.py", line 12, in main
    crldix = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(json.loads(data)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 60, in _convert
    return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: Fix the data first by `str.replace`?

Comment: `crldix = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(json.loads(data)).replace('false', 'False'))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(json.loads(data)))` is superfluous and redundant (see what I did here?)

`json.loads` already returns a dictionary, so there's no need to turn it back to a string then back to a dict with `literal_eval`.

Since `json.loads('{  "files": [   {  "name": "filename",    "boolkey": false  }  ] } ')` works, any problem you have is due to the way your terminal passes the string to `sys.argv`.

I don't know what OS/terminal you are using, but usually `"` is required in order to pass an argument with spaces. This will mean that you have to escape the other `"` in the string.

For example, on Windows, executing

```
import sys
import json

print(json.loads(sys.argv[1]))
```

In the following way (note the `\` used for escaping)

```
python test.py "{ \"files\": [   {  \"name\": \"filename\",    \"boolkey\": false  }  ] } "
```

works, outputting:

```
{'files': [{'name': 'filename', 'boolkey': False}]}
```

Another approach, without the need to escape `"`:

```
import sys
import json

print(json.loads(sys.argv[1].replace("'", '"')))
```

Then executing

```
python test.py "{  'files': [   {  'name': 'filename',    'boolkey': false  }  ] }"
```

works just as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I was using Linux system (Ubuntu 16) and running from bash